# Configure channel test timeout phoenix

Tags: sockets, testing, timeout, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a channel which I'm using to push messages to the client when carrying out some kind of sync:

```
defmodule AppWeb.SyncChannel do
  use AppWeb, :channel

  def join("sync:database", _payload, socket) do
    send(self(), {:sync, :database})

    {:ok, socket}
  end

  def handle_info({:sync, :database}, socket) do
    Process.sleep(2000)
    push(socket, "one", %{})
    Process.sleep(2000)
    push(socket, "two", %{})
    Process.sleep(2000)
    push(socket, "three", %{})

    {:noreply, socket}
  end
end
```

I have a test for this channel:

```
defmodule AppWeb.SyncChannelTest do
  use AppWeb.ChannelCase, async: false

  alias AppWeb.SyncChannel

  describe "sync:database" do
    setup do
      {:ok, _, socket} = subscribe_and_join(socket(), SyncChannel, "sync:database")

      {:ok, socket: socket}
    end

    test "socket pushes 3 messages", %{socket: _socket} do
      assert_push("one", %{})
      assert_push("two", %{})
      assert_push("three", %{})
    end
  end
end
```

But when I run the tests, I am getting the error:

```
Compiling 1 file (.ex)
...

  1) test sync:database socket pushes 3 messages (AppWeb.SyncChannelTest)
     test/app_web/channels/sync_channel_test.exs:13
     ** (exit) exited in: GenServer.call(#PID<0.478.0>, :socket, 5000)
         ** (EXIT) time out
     stacktrace:
       (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:830: GenServer.call/3
       (phoenix) lib/phoenix/test/channel_test.ex:360: Phoenix.ChannelTest.join/4
       test/app_web/channels/sync_channel_test.exs:8: AppWeb.SyncChannelTest.__ex_unit_setup_1/1
       test/app_web/channels/sync_channel_test.exs:1: AppWeb.SyncChannelTest.__ex_unit__/2

.

Finished in 5.2 seconds
5 tests, 1 failure

Randomized with seed 119011
```

How can I configure the channel timeout in my tests so that `handle_info` function is able to run for more than the default 5 seconds.

I have tried looking to configure this in the `config/` files, without joy and also in the `app_web/channels/user_socket.ex`, but again I can't find anywhere specify a `timeout`

Comment: Can you post the complete error message with the stacktrace?

Comment: added stacktrace, I can create a simple github repo to replicate the issue if that would make things easier

Comment: Hmm, there's a GenServer call at lib/phoenix/test/channel_test.ex:360 with no configurable timeout. Can you try changing `send(self(), {:sync, :database})` to `Process.send_after(self(), {:sync, :database}, 100)`. Not a real solution but might work.

Comment: After making that change I get:
  `1) test sync:database socket pushes 3 messages (AppWeb.SyncChannelTest)
     test/app_web/channels/sync_channel_test.exs:13
     No message matching %Phoenix.Socket.Message{event: "one", payload: %{}} after 100ms.
     The process mailbox is empty.
     code: assert_push("one", %{})
     stacktrace:
       test/app_web/channels/sync_channel_test.exs:14: (test)

.

Finished in 0.5 seconds
5 tests, 1 failure

Randomized with seed 282816`

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to increase the timeout of `assert_push` as well because by default it waits only 100ms and your messages come after 2 4 and 6 seconds: `assert_push(..., ..., 10000)`.

Comment: Great, that worked @Dogbert, happy to accept an answer from you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167016/discussion-between-sam-houston-and-dogbert).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Phoenix.ChannelTest.join` calls `Phoenix.Channel.Server.socket/1`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/56ec3c0c30d378dbfd3df4da5a08733cfcefb572/lib/phoenix/test/channel_test.ex#L360) which [makes a GenServer call to the channel with no configurable timeout](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/56ec3c0c30d378dbfd3df4da5a08733cfcefb572/lib/phoenix/channel/server.ex#L60-L62) to get the underlying socket from the GenServer's state. I believe since you send a message to self from your `join` function, that message is processed by the GenServer before the test code is able to get the socket value and since that call has the default timeout of 5 seconds, you get this timeout error.

A **workaround** for this would be to slightly delay the `send` to `self` using `Process.send_after/3`:

```
Process.send_after(self(), {:sync, :database}, 100)
```

You'll also need to increase the timeout of `assert_push` calls as the timeout defaults to 100ms while your messages arrive upto around 6 seconds later.

```
assert_push ..., ..., 10000
```

Again, `Process.send_after/3` is just a workaround. Someone more knowledgeable might be able to provide a real solution.